# How does "LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH" to remote hiveserver

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I want to import the file on the local machine using the "LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH.."

but, I can not import

```
$ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://example:10000 -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'tmp/file_20161024.dat' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE some_table PARTITION(dt=20161024);"

Connecting to jdbc:hive2://example:10000
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 2.1.0)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.2.1)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:23 Invalid path ''tmp/file_20161024.dat'': No files matching path file:/opt/hive/bin/tmp/file_20161024.dat (state=42000,code=40000)
Closing: 0: jdbc:hive2://example:10000
```

Perhaps, because the file was in local machine I think it was not imported.

How can I use the local file as the import file

I use beeline(1.2.1).

There is Hiveserver on VirtualMachine(example).

thanks!

**UPDATE**

I tried the following.

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://example:10000 -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/Users/asari/workspace/tmp/file_20161024.dat' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE some_table PARTITION(dt=20161024);" 

Connecting to jdbc:hive2://example:10000
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 2.1.0)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.2.1)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:23 Invalid path ''/Users/asari/workspace/tmp/file_20161024.dat'': No files matching path file:/Users/asari/workspace/tmp/file_20161024.dat (state=42000,code=40000)
Closing: 0: jdbc:hive2://example:10000
```

Comment: What do you get when you do something like `wc -l /opt/hive/bin/tmp/file_20161024.dat` and which rights does it show when you check with `ls`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess, but based on your description I would say you are pointing to the wrong location.

Presumably you have the file in a 'normal' local directory. In this case you would probably need to refer to it like in one of these two examples:

```
/tmp/file_20161024.dat

/home/asari/tmp/file_20161024.dat
```

Note the starting `/`

---

If your file is actually located in the location that you try now

```
/opt/hive/bin/tmp/file_20161024.dat
```

Then please check whether the file has any lines, and what the rights are to access this file. (If you are unsure which rights you need, set the rights fully open and see whether this helps, make sure to set it back though!)

Comment: Thanks, I use `/home/asari/tmp/file_20161024.dat`.

Comment: @asari-mtr That is not what you put in your beeline command, please change that and let me know whether that helps (if not, please update the question)

Comment: solved.
I understand that the command can be used only in the hive server.

Comment: load data from the local file system can only be used in "hive cli", not in "beeline cli".
You can only use load data inpath (from hdfs) in beeline cli.